# Datatables column filter checkbox not working with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

When bind datatables with ajax then I datatables column filter checkbox disappear. Here is my code

```
$('#Table1').dataTable({
    "ajaxSource": "js/Group.JSON"
}).columnFilter({
    sPlaceHolder: "head:after",
    aoColumns: [
         { type: "checkbox", values: null },
         { type: "checkbox", values: null },
         { type: "checkbox", values: null },
         { type: "checkbox", values: null },
         { type: "checkbox", values: null },
         { type: "checkbox", values: null }
    ]
});
```

Comment: http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/checkbox.html

here is the checkbox in filter

Comment: it is not working when I get data from ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing anything about what is going on - all we know is a comment about "*it is not working when I get data from ajax*" - and therefore assuming everything else is working great, no news is good news etc; and taken notice of `ColumnFilter` as being an old buggy plugin built for dataTables 1.9.x with +100 open issues, last fix was nearly 1½ year ago - then I would say this is a simple matter of javascript asynchronicity.

When using chaining

```
$('#Table1').dataTable({
    //some ajax stuff
}).columnFilter({ .. })
```

then `columnFilter({ .. })` is executed *immediately*, it does not wait until AJAX has finished its business. The result is that there is no data loaded at the time of the `columnFilter` initialisation. To prevent this, initialise `columnFilter` in a callback :

```
$('#Table1').dataTable({
    fnInitComplete : function() {
        this.columnFilter({
           sPlaceHolder: "head:after",
           ...
        })      
    }
})
```

Comment: Great!! it is working!! THank you so much davidkonrad :)

Comment: I have same issue with updatepanel(asp.net), I put datatable grid inside updatepanel, all are working fine, but when updatepanel called the checkbox column filter disappear, I applied your edited code but no luck

Comment: I asked above mentioned question on the following link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587656/datatables-column-filter-checkbox-not-working-with-updatepanel