# Datatables Column filter checkbox not working with updatepanel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatable, datatables

I have issue with updatepanel(asp.net), I put datatables grid inside updatepanel, all are working fine, but when updatepanel called, the checkbox column filter disappear...

```
$('#data-tables').dataTable({

        dom: 'RC<"clear">lfrtip',
        //"bSortCellsTop": true,
        colVis: {
            exclude: [0, 1, 2]
        },
        'bAutoWidth': false,
        "bSort": false,
        'aoColumns': [

          { 'sWidth': '15%' }
        ],
        columnDefs: [
        {
            visible: false
            //, targets: 3
        }
        ]
    }).columnFilter(
           {
               sPlaceHolder: "head:after",
               aoColumns:
               [

                   { type: "checkbox", values: null }
               ]
           });
```

Comment: you have not considered a `fnInitComplete` here too ..?

Comment: I applied fnInitComplete, but it is not working here :(